# Qual a diferença entre o element e o this na função $.each do jQuery

Tags: jquery

Durante o desenvolvimento fico em dúvidas o uso correto de algumas ferramentas, entre elas é no uso em um `$.each` do `jQuery` o `element` e o `this`, veja o exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $app = $('#app1'),
      $app2 = $('#app2');

  $app.each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    
    $element.addClass('color1');
  });
  $app2.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $this.addClass('color2');
  });

});
```

```css
.app {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
.color1 {
  background-color: #000;
}
.color2 {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app1" class="app"></div>
<div id="app2" class="app"></div>
```

Queria uma explicação e qual seria o melhor método para ser utilizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há diferença entre ambos, como descrito em:

> Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

O unico momento que element (ou segundo argumento) poderá ser melhor que o `this` é se for passar para uma função anonima, por exemplo se fizer isto:

```js
$("div").each(function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(this.className);
    }, 200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

O `this.className` irá retornar `undefined`, isso ocorre porque quando usado o `this` dentro outra função conforme o exemplo faz com que `this` seja igual ao objeto `global`, ou seja em navegadores `this` será o mesmo que o objeto `window.` (se for Node.js será o objeto `global.`);

Mas se fizer isto irá funcionar:

```js
$("div").each(function (i, element) {
    setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(element.className);
    }, 200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

### Extra

Note que `this` e o segundo parâmetro (element) retornam o DOM, mas você pode usar qualquer um deles para manipular com jQuery desta maneira:

```js
$("div").each(function (i, element) {
    var el = $(this); //ou $(element)

    setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(el.attr("class"));
    }, 200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

Você também pode usar o index (primeiro parâmetro) para associar o índice com outras coisas, por exemplo:

```js
var rightList = $(".right .item");

$(".left .item").each(function (index) {
    var el = $(this);

    setTimeout(function () {
         rightList.eq(index).text(el.text());
    }, 1000 * (index + 1));
});
```

```css
.left {
float: left;
}

.right {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left">
    <div class="item">A 1</div>
    <div class="item">A 2</div>
    <div class="item">A 3</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="item">Vazio</div>
    <div class="item">Vazio</div>
    <div class="item">Vazio</div>
</div>
```